# Verify if $f$ is injective and/or surjective, and then describe the inverse function which is bijective, also verify if $f$ is monotomic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, solution-verification

My professor give this exercise for homework, but due to distance learnig protocols, the class with this content was very unclear to me. I understand how to verify if a function is injective but can't verify if it is surjective, let alone if it is monotonic.

$f : N → N, f(n) = 3n − 1$

Verifying if $f$ is injective:
$f(n_1)=f(n_2)$

So

$3n_1 - 1 = 3n_2 - 1$

$3n_1 = 3n_2$

$n_1 = n_2$

Now, how can I verify if $f$ is surjective and monotonic??

Comment: Given a desired target element in the codomain, we'll call it $y$, can you find a choice of $x$ (*which will depend on $y$*) such that $f(x)=y$?  So... suppose for instance that $y=2$, can you find a choice of $x$ such that $f(x)=2$?  For this particular case, yes... letting $x=1$ works since $f(1)=3\cdot 1-1 = 2$.  Now... how about $y=3$?  Can you find an input $x$ such that $f(x)=3$?

Comment: Note that if it were the case that you could find it for any $y$... you would have had $y = 3\cdot x - 1$.  By rearranging and a bit of algebra, we would have $\dfrac{y+1}{3}=x$... so in other words $f\left(\dfrac{y+1}{3}\right)=y$... *However!*  Notice that $\dfrac{y+1}{3}$ might not be a natural number...

Comment: Yeah, following that line I found $f(4+3/3)$, and like you've said, it's not a natural number, so the $f$ isn't surjective, but how can I verify if it's monotomic, and i would like to know how shall I write all of this in my resolution as well, if it's not asking too much of course.

Answer (score 1):

It is not surjective since you can't find an antiimage for any natural in the form 3m or 3m+1. For example, imagine you want to find and antiimage for 1, then there would exist an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that 3n-1=1, so $n=2/3 \notin \mathbb{N}$.

For the other part, if $n_1<n_2$ then $3n_1-1<3n_2-1$, so this function is monotone increasing.

Comment: Ok, I understand the first part, but the second part is still unclear for me, could you explain in a different way, for instance, are you assuming that $n_1 < n_2$?
How did you come by this solution?

Comment: To see that it is increasing, you have to show that if you take two naturals $n_1$ and $n_2$, with $n_1 < n_2$, then $f(n_1) < f(n_2)$ (you can add equal sign if you change 'increasing' for 'monotone increasing'). And that's what I said before, if $n_1<n_2$, then $f(n_1)=3n_1-1<3n_2-1=f(n_2)$.